# Testing UNC path with subfolders

Tags: powershell

I want to test the existence of a sub folder on a file share using Test-Path and Resolve-Path.  First I create a share on my machine \someshare\somefolder.  Then using file explorer I add a sub folder so the entire path looks like this: \someshare\somefolder\subfolder

```
Test-Path \\server\someshare  results in True
Test-Path \\server\someshare\subfolder results in False


Resolve-Path \\server\someshare  results in True
Revolve-Path \\server\someshare\subfolder results in does not exist error
```

why does powershell not return true for the subfolders?

Comment: Could it be permissions issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issues here, sounds like permissions, try connecting as administrator?

```
& "net" "use" "\\192.168.1.1\psinstall" "password" "/USER:domain\username"
Test-Path "\\192.168.1.1\psinstall\app"
Test-Path "\\192.168.1.1\psinstall\app\subfolder"
Resolve-Path "\\192.168.1.1\psinstall\app"
Resolve-Path "\\192.168.1.1\psinstall\app\subfolder"
& "net" "use" "\\192.168.1.1\psinstall" "/delete"

& "net" "use" "\\192.168.1.1\c$\psinstall" "password" "/USER:domain\username"
Test-Path "\\192.168.1.1\c$\psinstall\app"
Test-Path "\\192.168.1.1\c$\psinstall\app\subfolder"
Resolve-Path "\\192.168.1.1\c$\psinstall\app"
Resolve-Path "\\192.168.1.1\c$\psinstall\app\subfolder"
& "net" "use" "\\192.168.1.1\c$\psinstall" "/delete"
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot re-create the results you say you're getting, but I'll note that your UNC as presented seems to be off.  A UNC is normally \server\share\folder.  You seem to have omitted the server name.  Is there any chance there's actually a machine on the network that has the same name as what you're using for the share, and that's what you're testing?

Update:  You say you've created \server\someshare\somefolder, then added \subfolder to the path.  You're testing for \server\someshare\subfolder.  Assuming your description of your folder creation is accurate, it appears you should be testing for \server \someshare\somefolder\subfolder.

Comment: you are correct but the problem persists very regularly.  I'll edit my original post.  Thanks for looking.